# How can emails be marked as read when moved to a folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there any way I can automatically have emails marked as read from a specific sender? I already have them setup to go into it's own folder, but now I'd like for them to be marked as read without me having to manually do it myself. is that possible?

Comment: Which version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2010.

Answer (score 14):

Edit your rule and in step 1 simply check the box `mark it as read`.

[image]

Finish the rule with the <kbd>Next</kbd> steps and save it. Now when the rule runs it will move the message to the folder you designate and it will be marked as read.

Comment: I'm confused, it doesn't give me the option to mark it as read.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) If this was the answer to your question, please mark it as such so others will see this has an accepted answer when they are searching.

Comment: Mark it as read (at least in Outlook 2013) is a client-side function, so your rules may not be processed unless the client is running. If you use Outlook for Web Access, those affected e-mails may remain in your inbox until the client gets fired up later.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to have 2 separate rules in outlook. First rule is client only: move to folder, mark as read, stop processing more rules. And a duplicate rule for the server side only: move to folder. The second rule will not work most of the time. But will work, if needed (e.g. another email client is used).

I'm not expert, but my guess, that a generic email server cannot store the email read status by design. (I know, IMAP and all... I'm not expert. Just trying to give some background thoughts.)

However, I saw in other mailing clients, you can create rules for emails already processed. E.g. not only for incoming emails. So Outlook definitely seems to be lacking some functionality here...

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.